# MS/Metabolomics R packages with VAST scaling

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am looking for MassSpec/Metabolomic R analysis packages that includes VAST scaling.  I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite an R package but web-based that does a great job! NOREVA : http://47.99.36.124/noreva/

or http://server.idrb.cqu.edu.cn/noreva/ and their paper is here: https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/45/W1/W162/3835313 Can point to some R packages later too....